# React native doesn't use the correct entryFile, the one I define is ignored

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

As the title says here is my **build.gradle** (I have tried multiple versions of this but none seem to work)

```
project.ext.react = [
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    bundleInDebug: true,
    bundleInRelease: true,
    jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
    jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
    resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
    resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
    root: "../../",
    entryFile: file("../../src/main.tsx"),
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

Or just this empty variant that is usually generated with a new project:

```
react {
  entryFile = file("../../src/main.tsx")
}
```

Error I get:

> > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED warning: the transform cache was reset. error The resource
> > `/Users/usr/projects/m/m-nx-monorepo/apps/myapp/index.js` was not
> > found. Error: The resource
> > `/Users/usr/projects/m/m-nx-monorepo/apps/myapp/index.js` was not
> > found.
> > at /Users/usr/projects/m/m-nx-monorepo/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:274:24
> > at gotStat (node:fs:2637:21)
> > at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>
> the transform cache was reset.
>
> The resource `/Users/usr/projects/m/m-nx-monorepo/apps/myapp/index.js`
> was not found.

I am defining to use completely different file than it shows in the error.

Versions:

```
Gradle: 7.5.1
react-native: "^0.71.11"
```